# How to optimize AnnotatinPositionChanging function in project with many Series and datapoints

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have an application that imports a list of signals and display its datapoints in a chart.
Like the picture below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzuce.png)

In the chart there is a vertical annotation that the user drags across datapoints and the Y values of each datapoint of every imported signal are displayed in a list.

My problem is that when I import a large file with many signals and many datapoints it takes a lot of time for the application to respond and when I move the vertical annotation (red line) it stucks for some time.

here is the code that I believe needs to be optimized

```
 private void chart1_AnnotationPositionChanging(object sender, AnnotationPositionChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        double pt1 = VA.X;
        int pt3 = (int)(pt1 * 10);
        int i = 0;
            foreach (var signal in Signals) //Signals is a Series List
            {
                double valtot = 0;

                for (int k = 0; k < signal.Points.Count(); k++)
                {
                    int pointVal = (int)(signal.Points[k].XValue * 10);

                    if (pointVal == pt3)
                    {
                        valtot = signal.Points[k].YValues[0];
                    }
                }
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(" ");
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = valtot.ToString();
```

I would be happy to see any ideas in order to improve my solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the majority of the time is spent searching for the a point at a specific X-value. This kind of operation can be greatly speed up by ensuring the items are sorted and using [binarysearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-5.0) to find the correct item.

Some other notes to make it a bit easier for the compiler to perform optimizations, this is mostly for when performance is more important than readability:

- avoid using `.Count()`, use `.Count` or `.Length` instead.
- Prefer using regular for loops, `List<T>` and arrays

Also, keep in mind to make measure the performance, so you know if changes actually does improve things or not. Using a profiler can also be a good idea.

Comment: You suggest to create a list with all datapoints of every signal and then Sort it and finally do binary search?

Comment: @WinDev1, you already have a list of all datapoints, i.e. `signal.Points`. This might already be sorted, if not, it probably should be. Ideally directly when it is created, so that you only need to sort it once.